# Are laws designed by statistical analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

Are laws in general created based on statistics? Or at least a certain type of laws like traffic laws? Is there any clear historical example of a law being created on the strength of statistical data? By "laws" I mean to say the kind of legislation and rules created by government authorities that are meant to regulate or restrict the behavior of citizens.

Comment: Please clarify.  In particular, are you referring to scientific "laws," rules of thumb, political laws, generalizations, or what?  What do you mean specifically by "based on statistics" and "strength of statistical data"?

Comment: I don't know if this is the sort of thing you have in mind, but the FTC can block a merger between two firms if the [HHI](https://www.justice.gov/atr/horizontal-merger-guidelines-08192010#5c) would exceed a threshold if they were to become one. The HHI is a statistic that measures market concentration. Elaborate statistical model(s) are used to predict what would happen to the HHI.

Comment: @Dmitriy That's not an example of creation of a law, though: that's *regulation.*

Comment: @whuber I think I am using the OP's second definition of law, which I agree is a bit non-standard. I agree with you that there is a distinction, but FTC was created by an act of Congress, signed into law by the president, and it restricts the behavior of citizens and others who engage in commerce. Measurement is a part of statistics (as defined by things statisticians do), so the HHI-based regulation seems to fit the bill.